# How to get new messages SQS without send the private key

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We want to use SNS + SQS to create a push-alike service to our system. We know we can do it and we are currently doing it, the problem is this:

The client will ask to the channel (SQS Queue) if there is new messages or not, but in order to do it, the client must sent the private key, which is a security hole, cause in that way, everyone will be able to sent new notifications to the sns service...

Is there a way we can avoid it?

Just to clarify: I don't have to send the PrivateKey, but I need to firm the request, and in order to do it, I need the private key, since this is done via javascript is insecure, cause I can not simply do:

```
var PrivateKeySoYouCanHackMe = "myPrivateKey";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I understood that you client don't want to send to you aws access key and secret key? In this case I would recommend to your client:
Create new iam user and grant access to your sqs only. Than get aws secret key and access key of new user to you. This help to your customer avoid security hole and control your account on aws.